# Scout error when using MAMP with WP-foundation theme

Tags: wordpress, rubygems, compass-sass, scout-sass

This is my first question on SO so if I am not adhering to the guidelines correctly, please let me know.

I am trying to work locally on a WordPress theme WP-foundation from Zurb. I have downloaded WP and installed it in the htdocs folder of MAMP and downloaded the WP-foundation theme and pasted it into the themes folder. I was able to set up the database and setup the config file. All of that seems to be working fine.

I want to work in SCSS using the Scout app. I set up Scout like this:

```
Input folder: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/testsite/wp-content/themes/wp-foundation/sass
Output folder: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/testsite/wp-content/themes/wp-foundation/stylesheets
```

When I tell Scout to start looking for changes I get the following error message:

```
LoadError on line 1038 of org/jruby/RubyKernel.java: no such file to load -- zurb-foundation
/Applications/Scout.app/Contents/Resources/vendor/gems/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/configuration/data.rb:161:in `require' 
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/testsite/wp-content/themes/wp-foundation/config.rb:20:in `parse_string' org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1088:in `eval' 
/Applications/Scout.app/Contents/Resources/vendor/gems/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/configuration/serialization.rb:24:in `parse_string' 
/Applications/Scout.app/Contents/Resources/vendor/gems/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/configuration/serialization.rb:15:in `_parse' 
org/jruby/RubyIO.java:1111:in `open' 
org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:298:in `open' 
/Applications/Scout.app/Contents/Resources/vendor/gems/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/configuration/serialization.rb:14:in `_parse' 
/Applications/Scout.app/Contents/Resources/vendor/gems/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/configuration/file_data.rb:7:in `new_from_file' 
/Applications/Scout.app/Contents/Resources/vendor/gems/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/configuration/inheritance.rb:204:in `with_defaults' 
/Applications/Scout.app/Contents/Resources/vendor/gems/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/configuration/file_data.rb:6:in `new_from_file' 
/Applications/Scout.app/Contents/Resources/vendor/gems/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/configuration/helpers.rb:42:in `configuration_for' 
/Applications/Scout.app/Contents/Resources/vendor/gems/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/configuration/helpers.rb:97:in `add_project_configuration' 
/Applications/Scout.app/Contents/Resources/vendor/gems/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/commands/project_base.rb:31:in `add_project_configuration' 
/Applications/Scout.app/Contents/Resources/vendor/gems/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/commands/project_base.rb:25:in `configure!' 
/Applications/Scout.app/Contents/Resources/vendor/gems/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/commands/project_base.rb:15:in `initialize' 
/Applications/Scout.app/Contents/Resources/vendor/gems/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/commands/update_project.rb:37:in `initialize' 
/Applications/Scout.app/Contents/Resources/vendor/gems/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/exec/sub_command_ui.rb:42:in `perform!' 
/Applications/Scout.app/Contents/Resources/vendor/gems/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/exec/sub_command_ui.rb:15:in `run!' 
/Applications/Scout.app/Contents/Resources/bin/compass:12:in `(root)'
```

I am pretty new to MAMP and Ruby so any kind of guidance on what is going wrong would be very helpful. I may be way off base but it looks like the Scout app is missing some compass files.

Thanks again and let me know if there are better ways I can interact with the SO community in general.

Comment: Looks like you don't have the `zurb-foundation` gem installed? Install it by running `gem install zurb-foundation` on the commandline.

Comment: @Kashyap I get the following error: ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions into the /usr/bin directory.

Comment: Looks like you are using the default installation of Ruby on a Mac. Try running it with `sudo`. Or, install [chruby](https://github.com/postmodern/chruby) which will make it possible to have different versions of Ruby on your system.

Answer (score 0):

For MAC OS X

open your terminal and check if ruby gems is installed

```
gem -v
```

if you get a version number try

```
gem install rubygems-update
```

or ( if you get an error )

```
sudo gem install rubygems-update
```

and enter your system password.
When it's finished just restart your compass app and try again.

Hope that was helpful!